# Kirchhoff’s law works in an RLC circuit with DC

Tags: passive-networks

Can somebody please explain how Kirchhoff’s law works in an RLC circuit with DC

Comment: You're more likely to get better answers here on the Stack Exchange if you can be more specific. What exactly do you not understand? Also, example circuits diagrams are very helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

For example, consider a series RLC circuit with one voltage source \$v_S\$.

By **KVL**, we write:

$$v_S = v_R + v_L + v_C = Ri + L\frac{di}{dt} + \frac{1}{C}\int^t_{-\infty}i(\tau)d\tau$$

Next, consider a parallel RLC circuit with one current source \$i_S\$.

By **KCL**, we write:

$$i_S = i_R + i_L + i_C = \frac{v}{R} + \frac{1}{L}\int^t_{-\infty}v(\tau)d\tau + C\frac{dv}{dt}$$

So, that's how KVL and KCL 'work' in an RLC circuit *regardless* (the extension to variations such as a resistor in series with a parallel LC should be obvious).

In the special case that the source is DC, the circuit voltages and currents are constant with time so

(1) the current through the capacitor is zero

(2) the voltage across the inductor is zero

So, for the series case, the series current is zero and so the voltage across the resistor is zero and the KVL equation becomes

$$v_s = V_{DC} = 0 + 0 +v_C \rightarrow v_C = V_{DC}$$

For the parallel case, the parallel voltage is zero and so the current through the resistor is zero and the KCL equation becomes

$$i_s = I_{DC} = 0 + i_L + 0 \rightarrow i_L = I_{DC}$$

Now, if you have a *switch* and a DC source, there are actually *two* circuits to solve and a transient that 'connects' the two DC solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Under DC you have inductors acting as shorts and capacitors acting as opens. From there you have a simple circuit with a resistor and an open. Should be easy to simplify then.

If you have an open in the circuit, then all of the voltage drops across the open and you have no current flow. If you have a complete circuit (no opens), then you have the current flowing through resistors according to Kirchhoff's law and Ohm's law.